# oracle bind variable storing date, returning identifier must be declared error

Tags: oracle

I'm trying to run the following code in Toad following the steps.
1.initialize and assign a date to a variable 
2. print it out to confirm 
3. then use the variable to check my when clauses for the date ranges.
Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

```
variable this_day varchar2(30);
exec :this_day := "01/01/2018";
--print to_date(:this_day, 'dd/mm/yyyy'); taking this out. print doesn't work with to_date()
select  to_date(:this_day, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual ;
```

--check  my when clauses

--check  :this_day  is between (apr1, 2018 to dec1 2018)>use this year
--check  :this_day is between (Jan1,2018 to apr1,2018)> use last year

```
select sysdate,
 case  
    when to_date(:this_day, 'dd/mm/yyyy')  between to_date('01/04/' || EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate), 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('31/12/' || EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate), 'DD/MM/YYYY') then to_char('01/01/'|| EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate))
when to_date(:this_day, 'dd/mm/yyyy') between to_date('01/01' || EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate), 'DD/MM/YYYY') and to_date('01/04/' || EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate), 'DD/MM/YYYY') then to_char('01/01/'|| EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate)-1)
 end  as reporting_date_from 
 from dual ;
```

> > ORA-06550: line 1, column 21:  PLS-00201: identifier '01-JAN-2018' must
> >     be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PL/SQL: Statement ignored
>
> UPdated:  error from the when clause  ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: i changed it to exec :this_day := '01/01/2018'.  now error says " Bind variable "to_date(:this_day" not declared."

Comment: now that you've corrected the quotes in your exec step, are you running all three steps as a script (i.e. together)?

Comment: use single quotes `exec :this_day := '01/01/2018' ` , exec and query will work. `print` does not recognize `to_date`

Comment: i'm running all 3 steps as a script in toad.  i'm also guessing the :this_day is also not passing through in the when clauses correctly.

Comment: ok when i do a "select to_date(:this_day, 'dd/mm/yyyy') from dual ; ", it confirms the variable is set correctly.  i'll update the above accordingly.

Comment: your last step should be `print this_day;`

Comment: now i get an error on the where clause .. 

Error at line 4
ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: btw, what is your select statement trying to do? Why is the reporting date for this_day = 01/03/2018 output 01/01/2017 and not 01/04/2017? I would expect the latter, since that's what you're using to decide what reporting year to use

Comment: it is trying to check  :this_day  is between (apr1, 2018 to dec1 2018)..use this year   else between (Jan1,2018 to apr1,2018)...use last year

Comment: But what should happen if this_date = 05/06/2017?

Comment: the scenario this_date = 05/06/2017 should never happen because it will pass the sysdate into this_day in production.  in this case, i guess it will break it.  I'm using the this_date variable to test the when clauses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invalid number error you're getting is due to the following part of your query:

```
to_char('01/01/'|| EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate)-1)
```

The concatenation is done first and then the subtraction - and since '01/0/2018' is not a number, you get the error.

You must use brackets to ensure the subtraction from the date is done first and then the concatenation, i.e.

```
to_char('01/01/'|| (EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate)-1))
```

However, your whole approach could be better done by using a with clause to create some test data, e.g.:

```
WITH dates AS (SELECT to_date('01/04/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') this_day FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('31/03/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') this_day FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('02/04/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') this_day FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('16/06/2018', 'dd/mm/yyyy') this_day FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('03/04/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') this_day FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('31/03/2017', 'dd/mm/yyyy') this_day FROM dual UNION ALL
               SELECT to_date('30/12/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') this_day FROM dual)
select this_day,
       sysdate,
       case
         when this_day between to_date('01/04/' || extract(year from sysdate), 'dd/mm/yyyy') and
              to_date('31/12/' || extract(year from sysdate), 'dd/mm/yyyy') then
          to_char('01/01/' || extract(year from sysdate))
         when this_day between to_date('01/01' || extract(year from sysdate), 'dd/mm/yyyy') and
              to_date('01/04/' || extract(year from sysdate), 'dd/mm/yyyy') then
          to_char('01/01/' || (extract(year from sysdate) - 1))
       end as reporting_date_from,
       case WHEN trunc(this_day, 'yyyy') = trunc(sysdate, 'yyyy') THEN trunc(add_months(this_day, -3), 'yyyy') END as reporting_date_from2,
       trunc(add_months(this_day, -3), 'yyyy') reporting_date_from3,
       add_months(trunc(add_months(this_day, -3), 'yyyy'), 3) reporting_date_from4
from   dates;

THIS_DAY    SYSDATE     REPORTING_DATE_FROM                            REPORTING_DATE_FROM2 REPORTING_DATE_FROM3 REPORTING_DATE_FROM4
----------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
01/04/2018  12/04/2018  01/01/2018                                     01/01/2018           01/01/2018           01/04/2018
31/03/2018  12/04/2018  01/01/2017                                     01/01/2017           01/01/2017           01/04/2017
02/04/2018  12/04/2018  01/01/2018                                     01/01/2018           01/01/2018           01/04/2018
16/06/2018  12/04/2018  01/01/2018                                     01/01/2018           01/01/2018           01/04/2018
03/04/2017  12/04/2018                                                                      01/01/2017           01/04/2017
31/03/2017  12/04/2018                                                                      01/01/2016           01/04/2016
30/12/2016  12/04/2018                                                                      01/01/2016           01/04/2016
```

Doing it this way means that you can test a range of dates in one go, rather than having to keep updating the value you want to test for. You can add more rows to get more test cases if you want.

I've included some additional ways of calculating the reporting date; the last is what I think the reporting date should be (i.e. if the date is after the 1st April, then the reporting date is 1st April of that year, otherwise it's the 1st April of the previous year). Feel free to play with them to see if they do what you want.

Comment: ah the (EXTRACT(year FROM sysdate)-1)) got me.  thank you for your help.  i'll try your approach.